# C# Examples don't working in Visual Studio 2013 Pro

Tags: soap, c#

I'm trying to get done the basics of C# and the SOAP API.
My target is to create an ConsoleApplication which synchronise every dataset from my ERP System to Salesforce and backwards. For example every product, every account and all the other thinks.

I use here the latest Visual Studio 2013 Professional with the Standard .NET Framework 4.5 and the latest SOAP API Version 33

I also imported the latest enterprise wsdl and fixed it by adding the line

```
<xsd:attribute name="tmp" type="xsd:string" />
```

as mentioned here:https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AiPEIA0

I tried the Walktrough Code here (the modern one with .NET 3 Code) mentioned here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_walk_through_code.htm

But I always get an error when using this code:

```
// describeGlobal() returns an array of object results that  
// includes the object names that are available to the logged-in user. 
DescribeGlobalResult dgr = client.describeGlobal(
                      header, // session header
                      null // package version header
                      );
```

The compiler says that no overloading of this method uses 2 arguments.

I got the same errors in the methods "describeSObjects", "query" and "queryMore".

Do anyone know why this example won't work? Or has the new API some bugs in it?

Thank you for help.

Tobi

Comment: Hi Tobias, have you tried to re-add enterprise wsdl as a web reference?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add wsdl as a web reference not a service reference in VS. Hope this helps.

P.S. If you are going to sync data in small chunks then Salesforce .NET toolkit might be an option as well.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the hint with the web reference.
I yesterday tried the Force.com .NET Toolkit
https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET

And this really worked and maybe I will use this Framework for my entire synchronization because with this I don't need any wsdl. ;)

Now I'm going to vacation for one week. So maybe afterwards I'm trying the web reference.

Thank you very much.